# Google Cloud Document AI can be installed and used on local, on-premise hardware?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I had a discussion with a female representative from Google Cloud sales. She claimed that ‘Document AI’ is now available as an on-premise solution. I have doubts about this claim. Can anyone confirm if this service is currently available for on-premise deployment?

Comment: Client libraries for the Document AI API can be installed on your local system. For more information, refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-python).

Answer (score 2):

There is not a full on-premises deployment of [Document AI](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai), but you can perform Optical Character Recognition (OCR) using [OCR On-Prem](https://cloud.google.com/vision/on-prem).

However, this doesn't include all of the same features as Document AI, such as the [Form Parser](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/form-parser) and [Custom Document Extractor](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_cde).